# HTML Inner Table With Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table inside of a table, I want the outer table to always be 100% of the parent's width with no horizontal scrolling and then the inner table to have a horizontal scroll bar (only if it has enough columns that it needs it).

Here's an example that is causing the html element to scroll and is making the outer table stretch, this is no good.

`Fiddle:` https://jsfiddle.net/w31Lhe8w/6/

When you show the inner table you see it stretch the outer table, and when it's hidden the outer table fits it's parent perfectly with no scrolling.  Ideally, keeping the html the same (except for some css classes of course) would be best as this html is what works best in my project.  Any solution may be helpful, however.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.

First, add `position: relative` to the containing `td` element:

```
<td colspan="6" style="position: relative;">
```

You then apply a new CSS rule to the enclosing `div`:

```
<div class="innertable">
```

as follows:

```
.innertable {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This seems to work pretty well for one or more rows of the inner table.

See fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/c7o3f0mp/

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is almost perfect.  I didn't specify that there can be multiple rows in the outer table. If there is more than one row in the outer table then the expanded inner table needs to push down the other rows.  See this https://jsfiddle.net/c7o3f0mp/2/